# How can I disable Cassandra from using TFastFramedTransport?

Tags: cassandra

When starting Apache Cassandra, how can I disable Cassandra from using TFastFramedTransport?

```
cassandra.bat -f

INFO 09:12:19,460 Logging initialized
etc..
etc..
etc..
INFO 09:12:21,008 Binding thrift service to localhost/127.0.0.1:9160
INFO 09:12:21,013 Using TFastFramedTransport with a max frame size of 15728640 bytes.
INFO 09:12:21,016 Listening for thrift clients...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cassandra 0.8+ only supports framed transport.  Non-framed mode is [highly unsafe](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-475), so it was removed.